# How to use storybook remotely?

Tags: reactjs, git, storybook, micro-frontend, storybook-addon-specifications

I am currently working on multiple projects(that means each project is in different repo) which is using storybook(one common repo which is getting redundant in each project). I want to publish or do want to place that somewhere on the cloud so that, code doesn't get redundant every time.

I am using storybook in my reactJS project.

Comment: Have a look at [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Thanks, @EnricoCampidoglio for the help.

Comment: How to manage versioning in it?